# strtotime summertime

Tags: php, strtotime

I have a strange problem:
I get some data from the mysql database which I convert with strotime to a timestamp.
then I compare these timestamps with a for loop:

```
for ($i=$start;$i<=$end;$i=$i+86400){
 $ptag=date("w",$i);
 if ($i<=$checkdateend){
   if ($wochendays[$ptag]==1){
     if (!in_array($i,$solvedays)){
      $solvedays[]=$i;
     }
   }
 }
}
```

with a given day (also a timestamp)
where  `$wochendays=(0,0,1,0,1,0,0)`

this works fine, but when I cross the summer/wintertime change I get a problem.
in the solvedays array there should be these values:

```
27.10.2012
28.10.2012
29.10.2012
```

but I get

```
27.10.2012
28.10.2012
28.10.2012
```

instead.
I guess the reason is the summertime change to wintertime, but I don't have any clue how to solve this problem. any hints?

Comment: You may want to store your dates in GMT.

Comment: i don't think this will affect anything, because i ve stored no time in the database, but only days. so i think it does not make any difference.

Answer (score 3):

Try [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.modify.php) :

```
$date = new DateTime('2006-12-12');
$date->modify('+1 day');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```